# Find an element when parsing HTML with jQuery no matter where it is

Tags: jquery, html

How do I access an element when parsing HTML with jQuery no matter where it is?

More specifically, why does this equals to `0`:

```
$('<div class="messages"><p>Just a test.</p></div><div class="messages">Another test</div>')
    .find('div.messages').length == 0
```

Where this equals to `1` like it should:

```
$('<div><div class="messages"><p>Just a test.</p></div></div>')
    .find('div.messages').length == 1
```

Okay, I can wrap everything into something every time, but really do I have to?

The problem is that I can't know if the element I'm looking for is the root element or not. In a given HTML document I need to find it no matter where it is.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33j35bh4/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter), to filter the root elements, [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find) will search the descendant elements of the root set to find the matches.

```js
 snippet.log($('<div class="messages"><p>Just a test.</p></div>').filter('div.messages').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

If you have only 1 element at the root, then no need to do that the `jQuery()` returns the root element

```js
snippet.log($('<div class="messages"><p>Just a test.</p></div>').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```